# I created 951 chickens in Riften. How do I get rid of them all?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I looked up the console command for chickens and stupidly created 951 of them right in the middle of Riften, as well as a single cow. I was claiming to make a farm, but this is getting out of hand. My PC is moving so slowly that I can't even see them all. Is there any way to mass-delete 951 chickens and one cow?

Comment: 951.... that's oddly specific. Did you count??

Comment: Well at first it was one chicken, then it was 50, and it stayed 50 for a couple more summons before I summoned 100 and then 500. So I just added up all the numbers and got 951. Then again some of the chickens fell through the floor, so I could be wrong.

Comment: Why!? Surely Morthal or Falkreath would of been a better choice. At least they could be caught by wolves or the Dark Brotherhood...

Comment: As for your.. Mm.. Serious question, there is a command to kill all NPC's (including animals) near you, but thats the town too... I don't really know the commands that well, so unless someone else finds a way, its time to start slaughtering... 1 by 1.

Comment: Paging Colonel Sanders...

Answer (score 6):

So I experimented a bit by recreating your situation and found a couple of possible solutions that I've listed below. These console command suggestions come with no warranty.

**However**, I found that after waiting roughly 30 seconds the chickens started despawning. So, perhaps you just need to deal with the clucking for a bit?

---

While this isn't the ideal solution, you can kill all non-essential actors with the following command. It will most certainly solve your chicken problem at a pretty high cost.

[image]

Command: **killallactors**
Kills all loaded (in currently rendered cells) non-essential actors (NPCs and creatures) immediately. Essential actors will be knocked down. The code killall can be used for identical effect.

[image]

---

I also experimented with the resetinterior command which will reset the cell to default (which lacks 951 chickens).

Command: **resetinterior**  
This command will reset an entire dungeon or location to default, including monsters, traps, chests and loot. E.g., ResetInterior Stillborncave01 or ResetInterior 00015206 would reset the dungeon Stillborn Cave to default; all monsters, traps, and loot would be respawned. If you reset a cell you have just been to, you'll need to use pcb command (purge cell buffer) as well, or the game will reload the buffered version of the cell, with all the modifications you've made to it. Both editorID and formID are acceptable in this command. Using this command in player homes appears to reset the furnishings without clearing the contents of initially empty containers (viz., the bedroom chest)

You can use [this](http://cs.uesp.net/index.php?game=sr&rec=CELL) site to find the formID/editorID

Sources: [Skyrim Wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console#prid)

Answer (score -1):

You could load your previous save. If you haven't saved in a long time there might be a command to kill all of them.

Comment: You need to **explain** that command to us. Pretend we know nothing. We have no idea where to find that command, you should try. :P

Comment: @FinnRayment `killall` or `killallactors` and then `resetinterior`.